# How can I backup an Oracle Tablespace and restore it as another tablespace in the same Schema

Tags: oracle, tablespace, rman

I am very new to oracle, I have an Oracle Schema (ORCL) that has two table spaces

1. TBS_PROD
2. TBS_TEST

I want to backup **TBS_PROD** and then restore it into or as **TBS_TEST**.

Is there a script or a tool that I can use?

Regards

Brian

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. A tablespace [is a logical storage structure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/logical.htm#CNCPT301) that doesn't belong to a schema. What are you really trying to achieve - do you just want to move tables from one tablespace to another? Or copy them - which would require a different name if you really only have one schema?

Comment: Hi Alex, am new to Oracle and the structure of the their DB, I have two tablesapces and I want **tbs_prod** to be backed up and restored into **tbs_test**.Do you just want to move tables from one tablespace to another? **YES**

Comment: You can do that with [alter table move](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2085301), you don't need to backup and restore. (Your naming suggests you have live and test data in the same database and schema; if you're planning to create new objects after you've moved the old ones, the names have to be unique within the schema - not within the tablespace. But that's going off-topic...)